# create multiple line graphs overlaid that are relative to each others numeric value rather than there own

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using the the Joe's Design's Raphael JS tutorial to build some overlaid graphs

I used the code to create 3 graphs that displays 3 types of info overlaid on each other but I have one issue that I cant't figure is why it hits the top for 200k and 50k at the same spot it doesn't make sense ?  I am trying to figure out how to make the size of the graph work so all the measurements are relative to each other but it doesn't seem to work ? Can any one provide some insight as to why this would happen?

It seems that each line is relative to itself rather than each other

I can provide any code that would help

Here's the js file

http://pastebin.com/NJj3whxZ

Also here's a link to my working example

http://theconfluencegroup.com/a_test/

thanks a million

Nick

Comment: i don't see any real problem with the library here. each unit has its own semantics, thus the oddity.

Comment: @EliranMalka thanks for the input I am just trying to get the largest integer to be the top of the graph and smallest at the bottom and all the in there respective spots. I guess my question is how do I combine the units and still have 3 lines that I supposed share semantics to get them to respect each other ? thanks again for your thoughts !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modifying the library http://g.raphaeljs.com/linechart.html 
allowed the max to be a setting:

```
var element = this,
            o = this.customAttributes.lineChart,
            settings = this.lineChart.settings,
            gutter = settings.gutter,
            width = settings.width,
            height = settings.height,
/*AeTky added: 2012.06.16*/             
            fixMax = settings.fixMax,
/**/                
            table = helpers.loadTableData(settings.data_holder), //TODO allow passing data by array
            size = table.labels.length,

            X = (width - gutter.left) / size,
/*AeTky added: 2012.06.16*/             
            max = fixMax == -1 ? Math.max.apply(Math, table.data) : fixMax,
/**/                
            Y = (height - gutter.bottom - gutter.top) / max,

            blanket = element.set(),
            p,
            bgpp,
            x,
            y;
```